# RESTful web service returns 500 error

Tags: web-services, rest, ssl, tomcat7

I have a RESTful web service locating in a domain name with SSL certificate (let's call this domain name/server, A).  When I call this  web service from my local box (without SSL certificate), I get the response back as expected.  However, when I make the same call to this same web service using a browser (I have tried IE and Firefox) from a server with SSL certificate (let's call this server, B), I get a 500 error.

At first, I thought it was a firewall issue.  But upon checking, Server A and Server B are within the same network.  So, they should be able to talk to each other on any port.  After that, I thought it is because of some security settings in my browsers being too high.  But after changing the security settings, I am still getting a 500 error when I call the web service using a browser on Server B.

The web service is written in Java and is run on tomcat.  Any idea on why I am getting a 500 error would be greatly appreciated.

The following is the stack trace.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
>     org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:116)
>     org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:323)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:113)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
>     com.pearson.ees.interceptors.NonCacheJavascriptFilter.doFilter(NonCacheJavascriptFilter.java:24)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>   root cause
>
> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault
>     org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:155)
>     org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:121)
>     org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:167)
>     org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:94)
>     org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>     java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>     org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
>     org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
>     org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:113)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>     org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
>     com.pearson.ees.interceptors.NonCacheJavascriptFilter.doFilter(NonCacheJavascriptFilter.java:24)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>     org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

Comment: can u also post the exception stack trace

Comment: Vineet, sure, I just added the stack trace in my post.